# Как выполнить действие по отношению к элементу при клике на все кроме него?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть всплывающее (выпадающее окно) нужно чтобы оно исчезало при клике например на body

```css
.popup {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #777;
  z-index: 4;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.enyel {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  background: #45a163;
}

.someel {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #bad;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="enyel"></div>
<div class="someel"></div>
<div class="popup">Мое окно<br>пока кликаем по нему<br>оно не должно исчезать</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так (кликните на область вне `.popup`):

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var div = $('.popup');
  if (!div.is(e.target) && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    /*
      !div.is(e.target) - если div не является "целью" клика
      div.has(e.target).length === 0 - если "цель" клика не находится внутри div 
    */
    div.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.popup {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #777;
  z-index: 4;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.enyel {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  background: #45a163;
}

.someel {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #bad;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="enyel"></div>
<div class="someel"></div>
<div class="popup">Мое окно<br>пока кликаем по нему<br>оно не должно исчезать</div>
```

Comment: а можете перевод этой строчки на русский написать, не до конца понимаю))
if (!div.is(e.target) && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов это значить что мы кликаем не по элементу, и не по элементам внутри этого элемента.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если исчезнуть полностью удалится)

```js
document.onclick = function(e){
  if(e.target.className == 'popup') return;
  if(document.body.getElementsByClassName('popup').length > 0) document.body.removeChild(document.body.getElementsByClassName('popup')[0]);
  
}
```

```css
.popup {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #777;
  z-index: 4;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.enyel {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  background: #45a163;
}

.someel {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #bad;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="enyel"></div>
<div class="someel"></div>
<div class="popup">Мое окно<br>пока кликаем по нему<br>оно не должно исчезать</div>
```