# Клик по элементу и вне области элемента

Tags: jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Вот мой `Jquery`:

```js
$("#hmrIcon").on('click', function(){
 if ($(".menu-responsive").css('display') === "none") {
  $(".menu-responsive").css('display', "inline-flex")
 } else {
  $(".menu-responsive").css('display', "none")
 }
 
});
```

При клике на иконку `"#hmrIcon"` выполняется функция в которой проверяется условие и применяется `CSS` свойство у `".menu-responsive"` являющимся блоком меню. Т.е появляется и скрывается по клику.
Попытка осуществить **скрытие блока при клике вне области** вот уже 3-й вечер неуспешны. Помогите пожалуйста!

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
 var $target = $(e.target);
 if ($target.closest(".hmList").length == 0) {
  $(".menu-responsive").css('display', "none")
 }
});
```

Элемент `".hmList"` является дочерним для `".menu-responsive"`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выполнить действие по отношению к элементу при клике на все кроме него?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704637/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be)

Comment: @Cheg я бы не стал закрывать вопрос как дубликат указанного вами, потому что тот вопрос довольно некачественный - простыня кода с одним комментарием, и ответы не лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрыть ваш элемент и выполнить дополнительные действия можно в обработчике onclick у корня. Однако если ничего не предпринять, щелчок по кнопке или даже внутри области меню скроет его. Чтобы это предотварить, отменим всплытие события методом [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

```js
$(document).click(function() {
  $(".menu-responsive").css("display", "none");
});
$(".menu-responsive").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$("#hmrIcon").click(function(event) {
  if ($(".menu-responsive").css("display") === "none") {
    $(".menu-responsive").css("display", "block")
  } else {
    $(".menu-responsive").css("display", "none")
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="hmrIcon">Нажимать сюда</button>
<div class="menu-responsive">Типа меню...</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Всем за исчерпывающие ответы! Движемся дальше, вроде получается.